# AJAX - Proper use of asynchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I can think of two simple schemes for using XMLHttpRequest.
The first is:

```
var xxx = new XMLHttpRequest();
xxx.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xxx.readyState === 4) {
    if (xxx.status === 200) ...
    else ...
  }
};

function getData() {
  xxx.open('get', 'zzz.php');
  xxx.send(null);
}
```

And the second is:

```
function getData() {
  var xxx = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xxx.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xxx.readyState === 4) {
      if (xxx.status === 200) ...
      else ...
    }
  };
  xxx.open('get', 'zzz.php');
  xxx.send(null);
}
```

While the first scheme makes more sense to me
(the xxx object stays alive even when the getData function completes),
It's the second example that is shown all over. How come it works?
Shouldn't the xxx object be killed upon the immediate return from the getData function?

Comment: Garbage collection is not instant, and you are still referencing the XMLHttpRequest object within the function

Comment: The first function wouldn't work if you'd call it twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

- Most of the time it would've been destroyed, but in function
  `getDate` you create anoter anonymous function that gets called a
  litle bit later.
- When that function is created, it 'inherits' the scope of `getData`
  function.
- So, when getDate is executed, the only thing that has reference to
  xxx object is that anonymous function.
- If you really want to lern more, google 'JavaScript closures'. that should give you deeper insight.